# BlinkM temperature indicator

Tags: blinkm, sensor, temperature, diagram, schematics

I want to build a BlinkM as a simple temperature indicator as seen at
http://thingm.com/products/blinkm/project-gallery.html
Anyone know where I can get a schematic & parts list?   The link on the page doesn't take me anywhere useful.

Comment: I too want to build a BlinkM as a simple temperature indicator. I am willing to pay for schematic and sketch code needed for complete project.

Comment: Hi Jules, I fixed the link on the BlinkM project gallery page.  Let us know what you make with a BlinkM!

Answer (score 3):

The link to the write-up went through a re-direct and doesn't come out right.  I do believe it is this:

- [ValenThrowieM + TempM](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2008/02/03/valenthrowiem-tempm/)

Answer (score 3):

Lady Ada wrote an extensive [blog post](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2008/02/03/valenthrowiem-tempm/) on this topic (which is what your article was referencing).  She shows how to work with the BlinkM, and mentions a sketch, but doesn't provide a link to it.  I can describe what the sketch must have looked like (in pseudo code):

```
setup:
  Initialize thermal sensor port
  Initialize I2C interface (for the BlinkM)

loop:
  Read and scale the temperature from the thermal sensor
  Send an appropriate color to the BlinkM, via I2C
  Sleep for a while
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty cool, we just has a student build one of these for an arm board. We took the I2C to RGB LED chip and pick an RGB LED. Linux was driving the LEDs.

On that note, if this is something people are not able to find more information on easily, I will do it for a PIC.

Hope everyone enjoys their project.
-Max